# Angular Reactive Form Changes when opening the form in edit mode

Tags: angular

I am opening the angular form in edit mode with prefilled data, lets say a draft version.
I have a requirement that I want to enable the save button only if the form has been modified by the user.

I have tried using

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.customerForm.valueChanges.subscribe({
      next:(value)=>{
        console.log('Value changed');
        this.enableSaveButton = true;
 }
}
```

However the problem is that this gets called multiple times when the page form data gets prefilled with the model.

Sample Code : My form is getting prefilled with model during init if model has some data.

```
this.customerForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl( this.user.firstName , [Validators.required])
    })
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `dirty` property of an `AbstractControl` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this on your Save Button. The 'pristine' and 'dirty' properties of the customerForm will inform you if any field in the form has been modified.

```
<button [disabled]="customerForm.pristine">Save</button>
```

OR

```
<button [disabled]="!customerForm.dirty">Save</button>
```

Comment: I will check this, but this is not about validation issue, its more of a "touched" form, that i want to track

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button [disabled]="enableSaveButton">Save</button>
```

If you prefill the form using `setValue` or `patchValue`, then `emitEvent: false` should be passed to not being recognized as changed.

```
this.customerForm.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
```

Comment: I am not setting the value via setValue or patchValue.                                                                      </br>```this.customerForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl( this.user.firstName , [Validators.required])
    })```